# Python, подсчет контрольной суммы CRC16, библиотека crcmod

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача посчитать контрольную сумму CRC16-modbus. Использую библиотеку crcmod.
На входе строка str_b

```py
import crcmod
str_b='010620010C4E'
str_b=str_b.encode('utf-8')
crc16 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x18005, initCrc=0xFFFF, rev=True,  xorOut=0x0000)
crc16=crc16(str_b)
crc16=hex(crc16)
print(crc16)
```

на выходе значение контрольной суммы 0xfd43, которое не совпадает с действительным 0xfe56. Если я представляю строку в виде

```
str_x='\x01\x06\x20\x01\x0C\x4E'
```

то контрольная сумма считается правильно. Как мне преобразовать строку str_b к виду str_x? А может я вообще на не правильном пути? Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Александр, строка `'010620010C4E'` - это последовательность **символов**, а не байтов. 
Вам нужно преобразовать её в массив байтов: `str_b = bytes.fromhex('010620010C4E')`

```py
import crcmod

str_b = bytes.fromhex('010620010C4E')
crc16 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x18005, initCrc=0xFFFF, rev=True,  xorOut=0x0000)
crc_int=crc16(str_b)
crc_str=hex(crc_int)
print(crc_str)
```

Результат: `0xfe56`